# forwardMessage method, just need some advice

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to make a telegram bot that can forward every message into another chat (inot supergroup, actually). I need to forward every message from every person who will text to this bot. So i think i have to use "forwardMessage" method in my code, this method have three parametrs required (chat_id, from_chat_id, message_id) but all I know is my id and id of my supergroup. Also I know message_id but I don't understand how to make message_id be a "variable parameter" so that every message is forward.

How can I do this? Is that even possible?

```
import telebot
import cnst

bot=telebot.TeleBot(cnst.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text (message):
    bot.forward_message(id, id, 86)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

This is something I alredy did and it forwards only "86"'s message, what follows from the code.

Sorry for English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `86` with `message.message_id`, that's all you need.